# How are different spellings sorted in the Daijisen dictionary?

Tags: kanji, spelling, dictionary

To to my knowledge, The *Daijisen* is one of the most authoritative dictionaries of Japanese, at least for contemporary usage. When they provide several writings for the same entry, are there any rules to their sorting of these writings?

I realise all of them could be considered correct, and I think brackets mean that part could be left out. Is the first spelling the recommended one? And if so, are the kana in brackets recommended or not? See for example すきみ (to peep):

Is the recommended spelling 透き見 or 透見? Or is there no recommendation at all?

[image]

I understand this information is probably in the usage information, but my Japanese is not good enough to navigate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the more widely used come first. From [here](https://japanknowledge.com/contents/daijisen/hanrei03.html):

> 漢字表記が二つ以上考えられる場合は、原則として広く用いられるものを先に掲げた。

---

FYI This kind of "how to use" is called 凡例{はんれい}.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any information on whether or not the kana in the brackets discloses any information about recommendation or most common usage? 透き見 versus 透見. I know it means it can be omitted, but I have not found any information on whether any alternative is preferred.

Comment: @timseb I think the following applies and it only indicates it is omittable. 省略することが許容されているものには当該のかなを（　）で囲み、補った形が許容されているときには語全体を〔　〕で囲って示した。